# addTarget and addGestureRecognizer not working, no crash/error

Tags: ios, swift3

I a have an overlay with a table in and I'd like to add a Tap gesture recogniser to the background to dismiss the view and also addTarget to a button within the overlay which does the same thing.

The overlay displays fine as expected, however whenever I tap the black background or the cancel button, nothing happens. I've searched for an answer here but nothing found has worked. My code is as follows, followed by a screenshot of the overlay:

```
class importedFileView: NSObject {

let blackView = UIView()

let importedFileContainerView: UIView = {
    let importedFileContainerView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    importedFileContainerView.backgroundColor = .white
    importedFileContainerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    importedFileContainerView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return importedFileContainerView
}()

let headerLabel: UILabel = {
    let headerLabel = UILabel()
    headerLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    headerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin" , size: 24)
    headerLabel.text = "Attach file"
    headerLabel.textColor = .darkGray
    headerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    return headerLabel
}()

let fileTableView: UITableView = {
    let fileTableView = UITableView()
    return fileTableView
}()


let updateDetailsButton: UIButton = {
    let updateDetailsButton = UIButton()
    updateDetailsButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    updateDetailsButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(r:40, g:86, b:131)
    updateDetailsButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    updateDetailsButton.setTitle("Attach selected files", for: .normal)
    updateDetailsButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light" , size: 18)
    updateDetailsButton.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    return updateDetailsButton
}()

let cancelButton: UIButton = {
    let cancelButton = UIButton()
    cancelButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cancelButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cancelButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(r:40, g:86, b:131), for: .normal)
    cancelButton.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
    cancelButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light" , size: 18)
    cancelButton.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    return cancelButton
}()

let frameHeight: CGFloat = 450

func showFormView(){

    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)


        window.addSubview(blackView)
        window.addSubview(importedFileContainerView)
        importedFileContainerView.addSubview(headerLabel)
        importedFileContainerView.addSubview(fileTableView)
        importedFileContainerView.addSubview(updateDetailsButton)
        importedFileContainerView.addSubview(cancelButton)

        cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDismiss), for: .touchUpInside)
        blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))

        layoutViews()

        fileTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width - 60, height: 230)
        let frameY = (window.frame.height - frameHeight) / 2

        importedFileContainerView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width - 40, height: self.frameHeight)

        blackView.frame = window.frame
        blackView.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.blackView.alpha = 1
            self.importedFileContainerView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: frameY, width: window.frame.width - 40, height: self.frameHeight)
        }, completion: nil
        )
    }
}


func layoutViews(){
    let views = ["v0" : headerLabel, "v1": fileTableView, "v2": updateDetailsButton, "v3": cancelButton]

    let leftSpace = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-20.0-[v0]-20.0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: views)
    let leftSpace1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-20.0-[v1]-20.0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: views)
    let leftSpace2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-20.0-[v2]-20.0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: views)
    let leftSpace3 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-20.0-[v3]-20.0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: views)

    let topSpacing = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-20.0-[v0(40)]-20.0-[v1(230)]-20.0-[v2(50)]-10.0-[v3(50)]-10.0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: views)

    importedFileContainerView.addConstraints(topSpacing)
    importedFileContainerView.addConstraints(leftSpace)
    importedFileContainerView.addConstraints(leftSpace1)
    importedFileContainerView.addConstraints(leftSpace2)
    importedFileContainerView.addConstraints(leftSpace3)

}

func handleDismiss() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   options: .curveEaseInOut,
                   animations: {
                    self.blackView.alpha = 0

                    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                        self.importedFileContainerView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width - 40, height: self.frameHeight)

                    }
    },
                   completion: { [weak self] finished in
                    self?.blackView.removeFromSuperview()
                    self?.importedFileContainerView.removeFromSuperview()
    })

}

override init() {
    super.init()
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you keeping a strong reference to the instance of your `importedFileView` while your overlays are visible? As far as I tested, all actions are silently ignored when the target is lost.

For example, this does not work:

```
@IBAction func someAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let ifv = importedFileView()
    ifv.showFormView()

    //`ifv` is released at the end of this method, then your overlays are shown...
}
```

This works:

```
let ifv = importedFileView() //keep the instance as a property of your ViewController.
@IBAction func someAction(_ sender: Any) {
    ifv.showFormView()
}
```

---

Programmatically generated `UIView`s `isUserInteractionEnabled` is default to `true`. You have no need to explicitly set it to `true`.

By the way, you'd better not name your non-`UIView` class as `...View`, and better make your type names start with capital letter, which makes your code more readable to experienced Swift programmers.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you. Will rename the class swell, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`self.blackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;`

is all you need to add to the `blackView` (`UIView`).

Without that, the view doesn't have any interactions enabled and so the gesture recognizer's target/action isn't triggered.

Events are ignored.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622577-isuserinteractionenabled

You might also want to disable it during animations.

Comment: I did try that but it had no effect so removed it again. I'll throw it back in and see if I can see anything

Comment: Added it back in and still not working. Also tried moving the addTarget and GestureRecognizer to the completion block of the animation to make sure they are not being disabled and not reenabled. Also printing out a line on completion to make sure the animation is reporting completed which it is.