# Add Gesture Recogniser

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2

For some reason the gesture recogniser does not work, it doesn't make the background normal again. How do I fix it so the selector (self.dissmissMenu) works?

In View controller:

```
let menu = Menu()
@IBAction func menuButton(sender: AnyObject) {   
     menu.runMenu()  
}
```

In Menu:

```
import UIKit

class Menu: NSObject {
    let dimming = UIView()

    public func runMenu(){
        if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow{
            dimming.frame = window.frame
            dimming.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
            dimming.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(self.dissmissMenu())))

            window.addSubview(dimming)

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                self.dimming.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    }

    public func dissmissMenu(){
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.dimming.alpha = 0
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Why duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946326/tap-gesture-not-detected ?

Comment: can you help or not? that wasn't answered i thought it was deleted i wanted to refresh it please help me

Comment: No, because I don't know what your issue. But don't duplicate questions. If people commented, they tried to help at least, if they asked for more info about the value of a var or something else, at least provide it.

Comment: i gave all info no one helped

Comment: "No one had the solution" When people comment, usually they are trying to help getting more info, or at least for another one that could see your question. But your question has only 4 hours. People have work to do, sleep, etc.

Comment: Are you sure that you have a strong reference of menu in your viewController? I tested your code and the only error it's that. If menu it's not a strong reference then dissmissMenu is not called never.

Comment: sorry I'm new at this. what do you mean strong reference

Comment: @james maybe this help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/40985988

Comment: @james, did you do a web search for "swift strong reference"?

Comment: @james, you should show a bit more of your research (as an [edit] to your question). You've written some code that doesn't work the way you want. What debugging or research have you done? How does the potential duplicate question not cover your case? This is an opportunity for you to figure this out with community help and then you might be in a position to answer the linked Question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite the call to `addGestureRecognizer` like this:

```
dimming.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dissmissMenu())))
```

Comment: nope won't work with#selector as its swift 2 not swift 3

Comment: Swift 2.2 has it.     navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self,
                        action: #selector(addNewFireflyRefernce))
}

func addNewFireflyReference() {
    gratuitousReferences.append("Curse your sudden but inevitable betrayal!")
} This is from https://swift.org/blog/swift-2-2-new-features/

Comment: it comes up with an error saying expected ',' separator        between before the #

Comment: Do you really must use Swift 2?

Comment: then when i try an add a ',' another error comes up saying expected expressions in list of expressions

Comment: dimming.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("dissmissMenu"))))
        func dissmissMenu(){
            print("works")
        } This one compiles without errors.Did ya tried it?